# Need to Install Apache on RedHat Without Internet Access

Tags: apache, redhat, yum

My client has given me access to RedHat server which requires to install apache but it does not have direct access to internet. So I cannot use "yum" command to install the packages.
When I ran the command

```
yum install httpd
```

It gave me this error:
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Then I manually downloaded httpd package and uploaded it to server and ran the command:

```
./configure --enable-so --enable-ssl --with-mpm=prefork --with-included-apr
```

Here was the output:

```
checking for chosen layout... Apache
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:
configure: Configuring Apache Portable Runtime library...
configure:
configuring package in srclib/apr now
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configuring APR library
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for working mkdir -p... yes
APR Version: 1.5.2
checking for chosen layout... apr
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/usr/src/httpd-2.4.20/srclib/apr':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
configure failed for srclib/apr
```

Don't know what to do next. Now I could not find any good solution by googling it